# IE messes up size of icon

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer the size of my icons are bigger than in Chrome. Im using em to specify the size of the icon.

HTML

```
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <ul class="block-help-list">
                                    <li class="block-help-item">
                                        <span class="icon phone"></span>
                                        <span>number</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="block-help-item">
                                        <span class="icon email"></span>
                                        <a href="#">mail</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

css

```
.block-help .icon.phone:before {
content: "\f095";
font-size:1.3em;
cursor: default;
```

}

font-size:1.3em;

Does anyone know a way to make this work on IE aswell?

Cheers,

mrjobby

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please

Comment: You need to give more details, impossible to answer in its current state.

Comment: Im sorry, I editted the post

Answer (score -2):

Just Give font size in pixels. Like font-size:20px; .

Comment: EM is supported in Internet Explorer since ages and you should really add an explanation why this would/could help...

Comment: I m not sure that IE supported EM or not. But I also faced this problem some months before, then i just replace EM to px by calculating the px in EM. And Problem is resolved.